# jquery resizable works incorrect in FF

Tags: jquery, resizable

If you open http://jsfiddle.net/UVsKp/413/ in opera it works just fine. But if you open it in firefox you will see resize icon in the bottom of display. How can I solve this?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your cell content in div

```
<td><div class="wrap">1</div></td>
```

And apply resizeble() to this div

http://jsfiddle.net/UVsKp/414/

Works in FF, Chrome, IE7,8

Comment: With `.wrap{
    overflow:hidden;
}` looks slightly better http://jsfiddle.net/UVsKp/417/